# cron job not running for node js

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I want to run a script that will add new records into the mongodb.

```
* * * * * echo ‘Run this command every minute’ >> file.log
* * * * * node /home/ubuntu/mongodb_tutorial-movies/getMovies.js
* * * * * node /home/ubuntu/mongodb_tutorial-movies/start.sh
```

updated code:

```
* * * * * echo ‘Run this command every minute’ >> file.log
* * * * * node /home/ubuntu/mongodb_tutorial-movies/start.sh
* * * * * usr/local/bin/node /home/ubuntu/mongodb_tutorial-movies/getMovies.js
```

updated code 2:

```
which node
/usr/local/bin/node


PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:usr/local/bin/node
* * * * * echo ‘Run this command every minute’ >> file.log
* * * * * node /home/ubuntu/mongodb_tutorial-movies/start.sh
* * * * * usr/local/bin/node /home/ubuntu/mongodb_tutorial-movies/getMovies.js
* * * * * node /home/ubuntu/mongodb_tutorial-movies/getMovies.js
```

here "/home/ubuntu/mongodb_tutorial-movies/getMovies.js" is the location of the js file.

Cron job runs for first script  i.e it logs echo text into the file.log but due to some reason it doesnt run the second script.

I also tried 3rd script but no effect. 
Contents of `.start.sh`

```
node getMovies.js
```

code for `getMovies.js`

```
var colors = require('colors'); 
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error);
db.once('open', function() {

});

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/movie-db');

var movieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String
, rating: String
, releaseYear: Number
, hasCreditCookie: Boolean
});

var Movie = mongoose.model('Movie', movieSchema);

var thor = new Movie({
  title: 'Thor'
, rating: 'PG-14'
, releaseYear: '2011'  
, hasCreditCookie: true
});

thor.save(function(err, thor) {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  console.dir(thor);
});

console.log(' every 6 secodns '.green);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons, Cron's `$PATH` contains only the bare minimum like `/bin` and `/usr/bin`. So likely `node` isn't on cron's `$PATH`. Solution may be to replace `node` in your crontab file with the full path to the executable, e.g. `/opt/node/bin/node` - you can find out the exact location on your system by typing `which node` in the shell.

Also, to run a shell script from the crontab, you don't need the `node` executable, so remove that from the third line.
The resulting crontab would then look like this (assuming `/opt/node/bin/node` is the full path, see above)

```
* * * * * echo ‘Run this command every minute’ >> file.log
* * * * * /opt/node/bin/node /home/ubuntu/mongodb_tutorial-movies/getMovies.js
* * * * * /home/ubuntu/mongodb_tutorial-movies/start.sh
```

Comment: @JP. Think you missed the point, at least you didn't change node invocation in your example. See my changed answer.

Comment: I changed as you said above , here's my changed file-  Also please don't make changes in the english / code indentation , this site request me to approve the chnages, but i don't have enough points to approve.

Comment: There's a slash missing in front of `usr/local/bin/node`. Should be `/usr/local/bin/node`. Also the second line (`node /home/ubuntu/mongodb_tutorial-movies/start.sh`) should not contain `node` in front, in fact you don't need this line at all if the third line is working correctly.

Comment: its working now.. thanks,  @greet3  how can i add this in the $Path variable so taht i dont have to write extra stuff ?

Comment: That's rather clumsy, please see the cron man page. I think it's way more practical to leave it there.